# #VALUE! error when trying to fill a cell thanks to anoher cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet called "sheet1" with cells A1 and B1 joined. The value of the joined cell is "test". The cell format is standard.

I have a sheet called "sheet2" with a column A in standard format.

When I try to fill A1 of sheet 2 thanks to the first joined cell with the following formula :

```
='sheet1'!$A$1:$B$1
```

I am getting the value "#VALUE!" instead of "test". I don't understand, as I don't do any arithmetics operations and all my cells are in standard format.

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure of the relative tags, as it was an excel subject, I thought that I could associate vba to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Cells A1 and B1 are merged, you just need to use:

```
='sheet1'!$A$1
```

Comment: No problem. I have run into this issue with reports I use that have merged cells. Doesn't make sense to me, but it works.